# Unable to convert associative string to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, search, associative-array

I'm using https://github.com/Loilo/Fuse as a fuzzy search PHP engine.

This works:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('diaplay_errors', 1);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$fuse = new \Fuse\Fuse([
  [
    "title" => "Old Man's War",
    "author" => "John Scalzi"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "The Lock Artist",
    "author" => "Steve Hamilton"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "HTML5",
    "author" => "Remy Sharp"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "Right Ho Jeeves",
    "author" => "P.D Woodhouse"
  ],
], [
  "keys" => ["title", "author"],
]);

$query = $_GET['query'];
print_r($fuse->search(".$query."));


/*
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [title] => The Lock Artist
      [author] => Steve Hamilton
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
      [title] => HTML5
      [author] => Remy Sharp
    )
)
*/

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="get">

    <input type="" name="query">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

But when I try this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require 'config.php';

$query = $_GET['q'];
if ($query == null) {
  exit('No query');
}

$sql = "SELECT title,uploader FROM `uploads_public` ";

if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
  // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
  $stmt->bindParam(":query", $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);




  // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
  if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Your search $query has the following results(normal json):<br>";
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json = json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo ($json) . '<br>';

    echo "While it has the following results when replaced<br>";
    $stuff = str_replace('}', ']', str_replace(':', '=>', str_replace('{', '[', "$json")));
    $json_results = substr($stuff, 1);


    echo $json_results . '<br>' . '<br>';

    echo "Here are you <b>real</b> search results:<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later. <br>";
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
  }
  // Close statement
  unset($stmt);
  unset($pdo);
} else {
  die("no input");
}

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$fuse = new \Fuse\Fuse($json_results);
print_r($fuse->search(".$query."));
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\vendor\loilo\fuse\src\Fuse.php on line 54
```

The syntax for `$json_results` is perfect except that it is a ***string***. That is where the problem starts. `$fuse = new \Fuse\Fuse();` requires an associative array as its parameter with such syntax as `$json_results`.`$json_results` is a string with the correct format/syntax as is required.

So my question is: how do I convert `$json_result` to an array so that the function `array_values()` can be used on it while still remaining the same syntax/format?

Comment: You're binding a value for `:query` to your `$sql` statement, but you don't actually use the parameter in your query - why?

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish by JSON encoding the data to then just replace the JSON syntax? Can you perhaps post your query output, and an example of what you'd like displayed on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have checked your code I can see that it's not string it's collection.

Try to use array for creating Fuse object rather than string.